# Since Push Notification with Instant Messaging

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, sinch

I am using the SinMessageClient to send the message. I need to support push notification in my code and I have setup the push with the following code:

```
NSString* userId = [options valueForKey:APP_USER_USERID_CONSTANT];
            id<SINClient> sinchClient = [Sinch
                                         clientWithApplicationKey:SINCH_APPLICATION_KEY
                                          applicationSecret:SINCH_APPLICATION_SECRET
                                                environmentHost:@"sandbox.sinch.com"
                                                                 userId:userId];
            [sinchClient setSupportMessaging:YES];
            [sinchClient enableManagedPushNotifications];
            sinchClient.delegate = delegate;
            self.push = [Sinch managedPushWithAPSEnvironment:SINAPSEnvironmentAutomatic];
            self.push.delegate = delegate;
            [self.push setDesiredPushTypeAutomatically];
            [self.push registerUserNotificationSettings];
            // Start the Sinch Client
            [sinchClient start];
            // Start listening for incoming events (calls and messages).
            [sinchClient startListeningOnActiveConnection];
```

I also implement all the requirement mention here https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/ios-managed-push/

It is not working and i have following query. 
How push message will be send if my application is in background?
Can i support push notification without support sinch call client?
I have only upload APN push certificate at sinch dashboard not voip push certificate. will it work for instant messaging app?

Comment: I'm stuck with a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Regular push works, no callClient required. Are you still having the issue?

Comment: I'm also not getting any push. Can you please help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577566/instant-message-push-notification-using-sinch-not-coming-on-ios